# Returned character is not being displayed

Tags: c

I'm trying to return last character of passed array using "char getlastc(char*)" function, but it is not being displayed in main(it displays nothing), though I tried many time to look for bug but could not found. Please point me the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char getlastc(char* array) {
   char c;
   while(c = *array) {
      if(*array++ == '\0') {
          return  c;
      }
   }

}


int main() {
    char array[50] = "Hello World";
    char *array1 = "Hello World";
    printf("%c %c", getlastc(array), getlastc(array1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This `while(c = *array) if(*array++ == '\0') return  c;` won't reach the `if` when `c == '\0'` because the `while` condition must be true. Anyway, not all control paths return a value.

Comment: Why are you not using braces? Number two just do one thing at a time

Comment: I've tried while(1) and then assignment of c with *array and after that if, but that not worked too and same results.

Comment: Ed Heal, I've used braces but same result, so for simplicity no braces.

Comment: @AhmadRaza some pretty nifty bugs have been introduced because of a lack of braces. Peter van der Linden would be disappointed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character returned by `*array++` is going to be the same as the character assigned to `c`. This is because we are dereferencing the pointer returned by `array++`, which is the value of `array` *prior* to incrementing.

Also, your function returns nothing in the case of an empty string as input.

Using a pre-increment and a little shuffling, we can fix this nicely:

```
   char c;
   while(c = *array) {
      if(*++array == '\0') {
        break;
      }
   }
   return c;
```

Now we will return the last character of the input string, or `'\0'` in the case we were passed the empty string.

As a side note, you probably want to add a newline character in your `printf()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `if()` statement in `getlastc()` never evaluates to `true`.

What you probably wanted to do is use a preincrement operator instead of a postincrement:

```
if(*++array == '\0') return  c;
```

Otherwise, you are testing the same character twice at each iteration, except for the last iteration where `(c = *array)` evaluates to `false` and the function exits (without a return value).

**EDIT:**

There's still a problem in that the `while()` loop is never executed at all when an empty string is passed to this function. Here's a simpler alternative:

```
char getlastc(char* array) {
    if (!*array) return '\0';
    while (*array) array++;
    return *--array;
}
```

Comment: Nice but missed the corner case of the empty string.

Comment: Right, but at first I've tried what you are talking about, i used preincreament in an infinite loop to check, but that not worked so I tried this, that is still not working.

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage you're asking for while(1) { if(++*array == '\0') { return *array; } }, but this does't works.

Comment: @AhmadRaza No, that's not what I suggested.

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage , great you've solved my problem,

Comment: The 'empty string' solution (`char getlastc(char* array) {
    while (*array) array++;
    return *--array;
}`) dereferences the element before the start of the array — which is not a good idea. I think you need a condition `if (*array == '\0') return 0;` before the loop.  Your call on whether to use `if (array == 0 || *array == '\0') return 0;` — I'd at least prefix that with an `assert(array != 0);` since passing a null pointer is really not likely to be supported behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Already accepted answer, but the function must return a value in all cirumstances. This handles the empty string too (returning a printable character).

```
#include <stdio.h>

char getlastc(char *array) {
    char c = *array;
    while(*++array) {
        c = *array;
    }
    if(!c) {
        c = '?';            // the empty string
    }
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    char array[50] = "Hello World";
    char *array1 = "Hello World";
    char *array2 = "42";
    char *array3 = "";     // the empty string
    printf("%c %c %c %c\n", getlastc(array), getlastc(array1), getlastc(array2), getlastc(array3));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
d d 2 ?
```

Comment: You're right, I'm still beginner, and you kind answers will let me up. Thanks.